# how to intercept PayPal IPN messages

Tags: magento2, paypal, preference, ipn

I was trying to understand what's the best way to read incoming IPN messages from PayPal. This need comes from the order workflow we implemented in our website. For example: when a payment is authorized, I would like the order to be set to a particular status. Then, when a payment is captured, I would like the order to be set to another specific status. I believe that IPN is the tool to use when you need the most accurate information about the transaction result, but apparently in Magento 2 it is not easy to reach that message.

So I made a module that extends \Magento\Paypal\Model\Ipn, working with the Magento DI **preference** way. The module I made resulted in a big copy-paste of a public method and 4 protected methods just to customize 2 of those methods. It is far from ideal. Also, the preference approach can lead to the good old rewrite conflicts.

The **plugin** approach is not an option, because the methods I needed to intercept are not public.

What I feel is missing here, is some event dispatching. I will open a github issue.

Anyone can suggest some other approach to read the IPN messages?

Comment: Check `sales_order_status_history` Table

Comment: Just wondering if you got any further on this and/or if you can include the github issue as I'm struggling with a very similar problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$orderId = 1;
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$this->orderStatusHistorys = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\History\Collection')->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $orderId);
foreach ($this->orderStatusHistorys as $orderStatusHistory) {
    $this->orderStatusHistory = $_objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderStatusHistoryInterface')->load($orderStatusHistory->getId());
    echo $this->orderStatusHistory->getComment();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a more robust approach, but I have to admit that yours is not bad.

Comment: As per @ermannob thanks as this is a completely different way of tackling the problem maybe.